# Gradle version issues

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting the below error(image) in my app's build.grade
It says all common libraries should use same version. But I've actually used same version. Below is my app:gradle file.

In example it shows com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.2.1
and com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0.

But my gradle doesn't include above two versions.

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.11'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'se.walkercrou:google-places-api-java:2.1.7'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Firebase and Google play services need to be same versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually run a script that looks something like:

```
gradlew dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile >> dependencies.txt
```

That will spit out a dependency tree and I can figure out which one is causing the conflict and either upgrading the lib reliant on the lower version or downgrading the lib working with the higher one.

For example, Firebase is currently up to 10.2.6 along with and relies on  `com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0`.  However, the latest `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+ -> 4.22.1` relies on `com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0` so until Facebook SDK updates to latest, I'm running Firebase 10.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Change google play dependency version 10.2.1 to 10.2.0
like that

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have my computer with me right now but try setting the firebase libs version to 10.2.1 maybe that is triggering the error